# Adding a wall outlet led to other switches and outlets to not work

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I added a wall outlet in my bathroom where previously there had been a plate covering up some unused wires. I connected the bare wire to ground on the outlet, white wires to one side, and black wires to the other side. Now the new outlet works, but the other switches and outlets that are connected to the same switch in the breaker box don't work. Did I just connect the wires wrong? What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: How where the wires before in the box, where they connected black to black, or separated with a wire nut on each one?  The outlet sounds like connected properly, you used the brass screws for black, right.  How many black wires were there in the box before?  All should be connected.

Comment: Did you add a new wire to each bundle (black and white) to connect the new receptacle? Or did you pull a wire *from* each bundle to connect the new receptacle? **Pictures please.**

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so originally in the box the black, white, and ground wires were all connected to each other. I had separated them and connected the separated wires to the receptacle. That was the problem. I now connected them to each other, as originally was the case, and added new wire to go from the connections to the receptacle. Now everything works.